# "admite que fuera" vs "admite que sería"

Tags: gramática, subordinadas

Recientemente he leído la siguiente frase ([fuente](http://www.marca.com/futbol/champions-league/2017/10/16/59e4a7aa46163f00328b45dc.html))

> El entrenador del Manchester City admite **que fuera** "estúpido"
>   esperar un encuentro fácil contra el Nápoles en Champions League
>   mañana en casa.

En un primer momento, me ha parecido que lo correcto sería:

> El entrenador del Manchester City admite **que sería** "estúpido"
>   esperar un encuentro fácil contra el Nápoles en Champions League
>   mañana en casa.

¿Cuál de estas es correcta? Si ambas lo son, ¿hay alguna diferencia de significado entre ellas?

Comment: Estoy en el móvil y me cuesta encontrarlo, pero ya tenemos varias preguntas sobre cuando los verbos en -ra pueden sustituir el condicional, y es algo que se ha notado por siglos y el uso va creciendo cada vez más.

Comment: no tengo una fuente pero "admite que fuera" suena realmente mal en español, al hablar se usa "admite que sería"

Comment: **fuera** suena bien para mí. No sé cómo son, sino subjuntivo tiene más sentido.

Comment: A mí me suena muy mal, pero quisiera ver esos ejemplos que menciona @guifa.

Answer (score 1):

El primer ejemplo es gramaticalmente incorrecto. El subjuntivo se puede utilizar cuando la frase principal está negada "No admite que fuera estúpido...". En este caso sería correcto utilizar el modo indicativo (El entrenador del Manchester City admite que es "estúpido" esperar...) o suponer que la frase subordinada está condicionada a algo (implícita o explícitamente), en cuyo caso se puede utilizar el condicional, como has propuesto.

Como usualmente el futuro siempre está condicionado, el condicional es casi siempre la forma más común, excepto cuando el hablante quiere enfatizar que existe certeza.

---

@walen: Gracias por el comentario, tienes razón. Ambas formas son correctas. Me ha confundido el hecho de que utilizar el subjuntivo es hoy menos común. Pero una búsqueda en google muestra que a pesar de estar el subjuntivo representado  alrededor de cinco veces menos, ambas formas se utilizan hoy en día.

Answer (score -1):

¡Oh, los atropellos de la voz pasiva!

Éste es un caso de pospretérito en voz pasiva, pero la duda es en qué momento fue esto dicho: ¿antes del juego o después del juego?

Si fue antes del juego esto es claramente un caso de pospretérito y entonces la forma correcta sería "sería".

Sin embargo, si esto fue dicho después del juego, entonces debemos recurrir a la forma disyuntiva del futuro perfecto: "fuese".

Aunque yo me inclino más por la forma pretérito pluscuamperfecto, en el cual la conjugación correcta es: "hubiera sido".